# Custom index.html for nuxt.js build

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Sorry if this is asked, just not sure what to search for.  Is there a way to change the template that's used to generate the index.html file when building a **Nuxt app** in spa mode?

Comment: There is no *index.html* with nuxt. What is output is generated automagically by the framework through several points of configuration. What are you attempting to accomplish here?

Comment: When you do "npm run build" and you have it set to spa mode in the nuxt config, there is an index.html file that is generated in the dist folder.  I'm wondering if it's possible to control what that html content looks like.  If it's possible, I'd like to have that only have the script tags rather than a fully generated page with html, head, and body tags.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For overwriting the `.nuxt/views/app.template.html`, you need to create `app.html` file at the root of the project. You can then, copy-paste the general content from `app.template.html` and start modifying things.

For eg - *I have to add the `lang` attribute to the `html` tag, so I have updated the code a bit in my `app.html`*

**app.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about Nuxt 3?

Comment: copy/pasted from https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14195, at least leave the source

Answer (score 1):

Like `@Ohgodwhy` said There is no `index.html` with nuxt.

Nuxt 3 :

You can use [defineNuxtConfig](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta#example) to fill the head for your whole application

Or you can use [useHead](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta#composable-usehead) in your pages to define programmatically the head of you page and those values can also be reactive.

Nuxt 2 :

You can change everything that you want with `vue-meta` that is used by default in nuxt see more : https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head/

Comment: There _is_ an `index.html` generated by Nuxt based on what configuration you have.

Answer (score 1):

**Nuxt3**

A long-awaited solution as a result of https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14195 discussion.

Create a file in `server/plugins/extend-html.ts` (yes, `server/plugins` folder, not just `plugins` in root)

```
export default defineNitroPlugin((nitroApp) => {
  nitroApp.hooks.hook('render:html', (html, { event }) => {
    html.head.push(
      `<script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-123456789'></script><script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}gtag('js', new Date());gtag('config', 'AW-123456789');</script>`,
    )
  })
})
```

as per https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-plugins it'll automatically import to your file while doing `nuxi build`. It's in `server`, so can't promise it'll work for `nuxi generate`.